# dismiss keyboard tapping background with action

Tags: swift, keyboard, touchesbegan

My app has two UITextFields. Both I have dismissing by tapping the background because they are using the decimal keyboard. I want it so if say textField1 is up and you tap the background a specific button pops up with the actions for textField1 and vice versa. Currently if you tap the background with out any keyboard up it still pops up a button. Any help would be awesome thanks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    button.isHidden = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textField.delegate = self
    button.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: I suggest to make use of IQKeyboardManager to handle keyboard related events. https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Can you explain in detail, what exactly you want to show? Do you want to show a button on dismissing keyboard? is that it?

Comment: Yes I want when you dismiss a specific keyboard a button to show up so I can do a specific action for that keyboard that is being dismissed. I also don’t anything to happen if there isn’t an active keyboard.